# Is there any C/C++ way for concatenating constant arrays other than macro?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I want to declare some constant arrays which have some shared part, currently I have to use macros to achieve this.

I want:

```cpp
struct Param{int a; int b;};

const static std::vector<Param> SHARED_DATA = {
    {1,2},
    {3,4},
};

const static std::vector<Param> TEST_DATA_ONE = {
    {5,6},
    SHARED_DATA,
    {7,8},
};

const static std::vector<Param> TEST_DATA_TWO = {
    {9,10},
    SHARED_DATA,
    {11,12},
};
```

Obviously the above code can not compile.

What I'm using now:

```c
#define SHARED_DATA \
    {1,2}, \
    {3,4}

#define TEST_DATA_ONE \
    {5,6}, \
    SHARED_DATA, \
    {7,8} \

#define TEST_DATA_TWO \
    {9,10}, \
    SHARED_DATA, \
    {11,12} \

const Param PACK_DATA_ONE[] = {
    TEST_DATA_ONE,
    {1,2},
};

const Param PACK_DATA_TWO[] = {
    TEST_DATA_TWO,
    {1,2},
};
```

Is there any C/C++ way for concatenating constant arrays other than macro?

Comment: There is no "C/C++" there is only "C++" .... ok or "C"

Comment: And yes there is, using function templates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Both C and C++ methods are acceptable, could you please share how to use function templates to achive this?

Comment: Are immediate lambdas [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/x5srro395) good enough for you?

Comment: Thanks! Looks much better than macros, but still a little complicated.

Comment: nothing is really obvious. Do you want arrays or vectors? They are not the same (even when considering constant ones where you cannot add elements)

Comment: is this a typo? Should `common_data` actually be `SHARED_DATA`?

Comment: Vectors and arrays don't really matter, I will use as arrays, and I can get continuous memory as array from vectors via `data()`

Comment: Yes, typo, I will edit it now.

Comment: So you mean you want to use sth like `std::array` and it also support something like `std::array<Param, new_size> arr = {{some_new_params}, old_arr}`, and `new_size` can be calculated automatically?

Comment: Yes! @LiuYuan And they are constants

Comment: Which means they are compile-time deterministic, constant, easy to determine size, etc. Wow, this is really strict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

std::vector is more of a runtime thing so you could make runtime functions for concatenating. However if you use std::array then you can combine at compile time.

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

// Compile time function to add one value to an array
template<typename type_t, std::size_t N>
static constexpr void append(std::array<type_t, N>& arr, type_t& value, std::size_t& offset)
{
    arr[offset] = value;
    offset++;
}

// Compile time function to add another array to the array
template<typename type_t, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
static constexpr void append(std::array<type_t, N>& arr, const std::array<type_t,M>& values, std::size_t& offset)
{
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < values.size(); ++n, ++offset)
    {
        arr[offset] = values[n];
    }
}

// Create a variadic template function to build an array
// from a mix of values and other arrays
template<typename type_t, typename... args_t>
static constexpr auto build_array(args_t&&... args)
{
    // calculate the size of the final array by summing
    // the sizes of the arguments divided by the size of the underlying type
    const auto size_v = ((sizeof(args_t)/sizeof(type_t)) + ...);
    std::array<type_t, size_v> values{};

    // start adding values at the start of the array
    std::size_t offset{0ul};

    // the compiler will select the correct append function to use at compile time
    // what you see here is a fold expression and it will "loop" over all args
    (append(values, args, offset),...);

    return values;
}


int main()
{
    constexpr std::array arr1{ 2, 3 };
    constexpr std::array arr2{ 5, 6 };

    constexpr auto arr3 = build_array<int>(1, arr1, 4, arr2, 7);

    static_assert(arr3.size() == 7);
    static_assert(arr3[0] == 1);
    static_assert(arr3[1] == 2);
    static_assert(arr3[2] == 3);
    static_assert(arr3[3] == 4);
    static_assert(arr3[4] == 5);
    static_assert(arr3[5] == 6);
    static_assert(arr3[6] == 7);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sir, I discover that your `std::array` in `main` declared without template parameters. I am only familiar with std11, I searched that this is a std17 feature but I didn't find official doc, could you please provide a doc link?

Comment: It is called CTAD : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm searching with `template parameter autoinferential` keywords and got nothing

Answer (score 2):

A solution to get close to what you want:

```cpp
struct Param { int a; int b; };

template<typename T, typename V>
concept ConcatType = std::is_same_v<std::vector<V>, T> || std::is_constructible_v<V, T>;

template<typename T>
struct ConcatHelper : std::vector<T>
{
    template<typename... ConcatType>
    ConcatHelper(ConcatType&&... args)
    {
        (add(std::forward<ConcatType>(args)), ...);
    }

    void add(T&& value) 
    { 
        std::vector<T>::push_back(std::forward<T>(value));
    }

    void add(const std::vector<T>& values)
    {
        std::vector<T>::insert(std::vector<T>::end(), values.begin(), values.end());
    }
};

const static std::vector SHARED_DATA = ConcatHelper<Param>{
    Param{1,2},
    Param{3,4}
};

const static std::vector TEST_DATA_ONE = ConcatHelper<Param>{
    Param{5,6},
    SHARED_DATA,
    Param{7,8},
};

const static std::vector TEST_DATA_TWO = ConcatHelper<Param>{
    Param{9,10},
    SHARED_DATA,
    Param{11,12},
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating two `std::arrays` at compile time is actually much simpler than what is suggested in the other answers.

```
template<class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
constexpr std::array<T, N + M>
concat_arrays(const std::array<T, N>& a, const std::array<T, M>& b)
{
    // If std::copy is not constexpr in your preferred standard library, just roll your own trivial copy loop.
    std::array<T, N + M> ret;
    const auto it = std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), ret.begin());
    std::copy(b.begin(), b.end(), it);
    return ret;
}
```

Demo available [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xa1rqqP9E)